# CSS for td in table using a wildcard

Tags: css, html-table, wildcard

I'm having some trouble with some CSS. I have a number of unique tables with a similar format name, and I need to set the background color on some of them. However, if I try and use a wildcard the style gets overwritten by a parent CSS file.

The background colour here works fine:

```
#AllProtectedServers1 td.status.online{
    color: green;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But the background colour doesn't work here as it's being overwritten higher up (although everything else does):

```
td.status.online {
    color: green;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I'm going to have 20+ tables all starting with "AllProtectedServers", so naming them all individually is going to make the css huge. Is there anyway I could use a wildcard? I've tried using `div[id^='id_']` and similar selectors without any luck.

Anyone have any ideas of what I could use instead?

Update:
Please note the ID's *are* unique (AllProtectedServersCompany1, AllProtectedServersCompany2, etc), but they all start with AllProtectedServers. I want to create some CSS that will override the stylesheet for the table that is overriding my changes and use a wildcard so I don't have to specify each one.

Comment: NEVER use id selectors in your css, you are not able to overwrite it ever... except inline styles which you should never use.

Moreover an ID is unique (that's why it is called identifier), consider using classes, especially for styling elements.

Comment: @alpipego "Never" is a bit strong. Using ID in CSS is poweful. I use it often, but it is important for the OP to understand [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: @specificity I meant never as in "never", there is no use in using IDs in css. Check http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/ or http://css-tricks.com/a-line-in-the-sand/ like never as in never ever. It is not powerful it is simply a pain (especially when working with css that's not your own).

Comment: A little HTML to provide context would be helpful, as would the style that is overiding your desired style

Comment: @alpipego, I believe you are inccorect in your assumption that the OP has duplicate IDs. It seems they have used an ID and therefore specificity, to have a work around, but he does not want to apply an ID to every table. `#AllProtectedServers1` implies there could be a `#AllProtectedServers2`, `#AllProtectedServers3` etc. The use of a wildcard in an the attribute supports this.

Comment: @JonP then we need more code. It is not perceptible by what the OP has provided so far.

Comment: You should show an example, with HTML and CSS, preferably a minimal case, showing what you have actually tried. It seems that people have now misunderstood what you mean and discuss solutions to quite different problems.

Comment: You need to find out what the overriding rule is and to make your selector more specific by adding components to it. The question does not give any hint of what that rule might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help:

```
td.status.online
{
   color: green;
   background-color: yellow !important;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Comment: This is perfect! I want to highlight errors which are, important. :) Thanks!

Comment: I am going to point out this is the simplest but worst way to do it. `!important` is very much a last resort and is generally a sign of not understanding the problem and CSS Specificity rules. Please take the time to read the following article on where to use `!important`: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: IMO `!important` is like putting a band-aid on a snake bite. You can't see the problem any more, but it is stil there and will still take you down in the end.

Comment: @JonP Can't agree more with you. It's a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alpipego's comment is not correct.  You're perfectly fine using ID selectors (#) for CSS.  These can be overwritten by other ID selectors of the same or higher specificity (depending on page order) or the `!important` rule.

However, you want to avoid using `!important` as a CSS rule because that can back you into a corner and become a maintenance nightmare.

As a matter of fact what you need to learn about is CSS Specificity.  I recommend reading the CSS: Specificity Wars for an entertaining but educational overview of how CSS Specificity works.

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Smashing Magazine also published an article on it that's more extensive:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

You do want to be careful about not going crazy with specificity.  ID's are (supposed to be) unique per page, so if you end up with a lot of deeply nested rules (#foo .bar .baz .goo), you're probably looking at needing some refactoring.

So, if you use Chrome, pop open the developer tool and look at the CSS selector and determine the specificity.  All you need to do is:

a) Match the specificity but make your style come later in the DOM page order
or
b) Use a higher specificity

That's all there really is to it.

I hope that helps!

Cheers.

Comment: please see my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705005/css-for-td-in-table-using-a-wildcard?noredirect=1#comment42003324_26705005 one of the problems is, that the OP is using multiple elements with the same ID on the same page. And you should never use them in css. Never! There is no use.

Comment: Please also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity on `!important`, it has nothing to do with specifity.

Comment: @alpipego, this answer does not say that !important has anything to do with specificity.

Comment: @JonP that is correct, but it is on a site mainly dealing with best practices and language singularities: if he hadn't used multiple elements with the same ID on the same page he'd never been running into the trouble he is in. Your answer is not an answer to the question, but a mere comment on specificity (as are my comments).

Answer (score 0):

[jmbertucci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705005/css-for-td-in-table-using-a-wildcard/26705190#26705190) is quite correct, if perhaps a little incomplete, I will expand with some examlpes.

One of the most overlooked aspects of CSS is specificity rules. As mentioned by jmbertucci please see:

- http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/
- http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html
- A little more googling will present a wealth of articles for you.

Let's take some base html and css and a bit of a guess as to what you have.

**HTML**

```
<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="status online">Online</td>
        <td class="status offline">Offline</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.myTable td.status
{
    background-color:#fff;
}

td.status.online
{
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66f9noky/)

This will result in a white background for "online" as `table.myTable td.status` is more specific than `td.status.online`.

In this example we need to make the second selector more specific. As you mentioned adding an ID results in what you want as IDs have an extremely high specificity score and a very hard to over-write. So much so that some say never to use them<sup>*</sup>. A simple solution in this example is to add `table` to the seconde selector.

```
table td.status.online
{
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

This results in a red background for "online"

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66f9noky/1/)

Adding `table` may not work in your instance. YOu need to find the style rule that is being applied using Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug for Firefox and create a rule that is more specific.

If you provide more information I may be able to provide a more specific answer.

<sup>*</sup> **A note on ID's** ID's extremely high specificty is both their strenth and weakness. I believe they can be used, but with caution. If you want to style a specific part of a page in a specific manner, you *may* have a canditate for ID. Think along the lines of a header and footer before the days of HTML5. Another good example may be `<section id="discalimer">`, using an ID provies two benifits: it's an anchor for specific styling and it can be linked to, e.g: `<a href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>`. A further read: http://www.zeldman.com/2012/11/21/in-defense-of-descendant-selectors-and-id-elements/

Keep in mind the arguments on weather to use IDs or not are a matter of optinion and their are good points on both sides. W3C, the standards guys, [has no stance on this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html). If where you work has a coding guide, stick to that mandate. If you're unsure, don't use them in CSS to be safe. Most importantly keep IDs unique.

Answer (score 0):

Andy68man, no wildcard needed, just use a class. Same class for all the tables if they all share the same properties. As in (first the HTML):

```
<table class="allProtectedServers"> ..... </table>
<table class="allProtectedServers"> ..... </table>
<table class="allProtectedServers secondClass"> ..... </table>
```

and the CSS:

```
.AllProtectedServers td.status.online { ... }
```

If there are one or more properties that only some of the tables have, create another class and give those particular tables both classes, as in the third line of HTML above.

Alternatively, if that still gets overruled by the CSS above, put a single div round all the tables or even the whole page (or there may already be one), give the div an id, and add that into your selector to increase it's specificty (your first bit of code above shows the extra id will be enough to overrule the other CSS that's causing your problem):

```
#myDiv td.status.online { ... }
```